# SAS Change values of Variables without 3 Data Steps

Tags: sas

Often when I am coding in SAS, I need to change values of variables, like turning a character into a numeric, or rounding values. Because of how SAS works as far as I know, I often have to do it in three steps, like so:

```
data change;
    set raw;
    words = put(zipcode, $5.);
run;

data drop;
    set change;
    drop zipcode;
run;

data rename;
    set drop;
    rename words = "zipcode";
run;
```

Is there a way to do something like this in a single data or proc step, rather than having to type out three? And not just for a variable type conversion, but for things like the ROUND statement as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ROUND statement?  Did you mean a call to the ROUND() function?  Since that would normally not need to change data types there probably is no need for rename or drop when using the ROUND() function to truncate values to a particular level of precision.

Answer (score 2):

This is where dataset options are a huge advantage. They work in the DATA Step, SQL, and almost every PROC where a dataset is referenced.

You can do all of this in a single data step multiple ways.

**1. An output dataset option**

```
data change(rename=(words = zipcode) );
    set raw;
    words = put(zipcode, $5.);

    drop zipcode;
run;
```

Here's what's happening:

1. `words` is created in the dataset
2. At the end of the data step, `zipcode` is dropped.
3. As the very last step after `zipcode` is dropped, `words` is renamed to `zipcode`

This is called an output dataset option. It's the last thing that happens before the dataset is finally written.

**2. An input dataset option**

```
data change;
    set raw(rename=(zipcode = _zipcode) );
    words = put(_zipcode, $5.);

    drop _zipcode;
run;
```

Here's what's happening:

1. Before `raw` is read, `zipcode` is renamed to `_zipcode`
2. `words` is created
3. `_zipcode` is dropped from the dataset

Input/output dataset options are very powerful. You can create special `where` clauses, indices, compress data, and much more using them.

You can view all of the available dataset options here:
https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/ledsoptsref/p1pczmnhbq4axpn1l15s9mk6mobp.htm

Comment: Thanks this is helpful, what would the formatting be to do multiple variables in one step for the output datastep?

Comment: `(rename=(var1 = _var2 var2 = _var2 var3 = _var3 ... varn = _varn) )`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do that in three steps.  One step is enough.

```
data rename;
    set raw;
    words = put(zipcode, $5.);
    drop zipcode;
    rename words = zipcode;
run;
```